# JavaFX - Dialog box displays blank on first time displayed

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, dialog

In my javafx application I have a dialog box which shows the results from a previous action. When first displayed the window just shows as white without the contents. After resizing the contents display, and on the subsequent times the dialog is brought up it behaves normally. I'm sure it's something simple, but it's been bugging me for days while I move to work on other parts. My initialize method and Constructor are empty and something tells me this may be the issue.

In MainApp extends Application:
called from another dialog stage controller after calling close.

```
   public void showEDResult(List<String> path) {
    try {
        // Load the fxml file and create a new stage for the popup
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(MainApp.class.getResource("view/EDResultLayout.fxml"));
        VBox page = (VBox) loader.load();
        Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
        dialogStage.setTitle("Edit Distance Result");
        //dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        dialogStage.setScene(scene);

        // Set reference to stage in controller
        //BUG -- when first displayed results don't show up until resize window
        EDResultController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
        controller.setMainApp(this);

        // give controller reference to result
        controller.setResult(path);


        // give controller reference to scene (cursor)

        // Show the dialog and wait until the user closes it
        dialogStage.showAndWait();




    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Exception gets thrown if the fxml file could not be loaded
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In class ResultController:

```
public void setResult(List<String> result) {

    numStepsLabel.setText(Integer.toString(result.size()-2));

    //TODO -- work on layout
    String str = buildResultString(result);
    pathLabel.setText(str);
```

}

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE] that displays the same behavior? There's nothing obviously wrong with your code, and code similar to this (even with all the ugly coupling in the controller class ;) ) works just fine all the time. So your error (or your code that makes a bug manifest itself, if it's a bug) is in your other code.  Without a complete, runnable example, it's almost impossible to say what's happening.

Comment: I'm going to try to create an example such as this today. About the ugly coupling though, care to explain/offer a hint towards better solution?

Comment: I can't really, because I don't see the code that shows why you need a reference to the `Stage` (why can't you just call `getScene().getWindow()` on a node?) or to the `Application` (just, why??) in the controller. But those are bad practice imho. But that is really incidental to your question.

Comment: I haven't been abble to create a MCV example unfortunately. I'm not sure about rules with this, but is there any chance you'd be be able to take a look at my project somehow and check out this issue and maybe give other suggestions? I'm new to JavaFX and feel like having someone with more experience look it over could be very valuable.

Comment: Also, the only time I need a reference to the dialog Stage is to call the close() method on a button action.

Comment: Your request is really a consulting request and beyond the scope of what I think is appropriate to contribute on SO, so no, sorry. You need to start afresh, then keep adding parts of your actual functionality in until you reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue after upgrading to Windows 10. It could be an unfortunate bug in the Java implementation for the new OS. I noticed an overall slowdown of JavaFX apps under it - if you'd like more stability, maybe try staying with Windows <=8.1 for now.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS.

Comment: @dinvlad I'm experiencing this also. Did you find a work-around?

Comment: @devouredelysium I'm experiencing this also. Did you find a work-around?

Comment: Sorry, it was too long ago, I don't remember the workaround now :-) But I do remember I got it working on Windows 10

Comment: Just chiming in to say I'm experiencing this also with JavaFX 17 on macOS.